# Extract/cut strings the matching lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to extract/cut some part from the beginning of matching lines in my file. Remove all before matching [SUCCESS] & [FAILURE] lines.
content is similar as below

```
[1] 10:32:54 [SUCCESS] host123
hyujhbjbhjbjk cbcjd
yuiiiik,,................
[2] 10:32:54 [FAILURE] host123
jbjk cbcjd
yuiiiik,,................
[3] 10:32:54 [SUCCESS] host12356
jhbjbhjbjk cbcjd
yuiiiik,,................

Need expected as below output. with one space/blank line

[SUCCESS] host123
hyujhbjbhjbjk cbcjd
yuiiiik,,................

[FAILURE] host123
jbjk cbcjd
yuiiiik,,................

[SUCCESS] host12356
jhbjbhjbjk cbcjd
yuiiiik,,................
```

I am trying below sed command , but not helping

```
sed -n 's/^.*[SUCCESS]/[SUCCESS]/p'
sed -n 's/^.*[FAILURE]/[FAILURE]/p'
```

Comment: Remove `-n` and remove the last `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should :

- escape the `[` in your search pattern
- stop using the `-n` flag and rely on automatic printing

If you don't mind a leading empty line I would use the following, which leverages capturing group and backreference :

```
sed -E 's/.*(\[SUCCESS\]|\[FAILURE\])/\n\1/' file
```

or

```
sed -E 's/.*\[(SUCCESS|FAILURE)\]/\n[\1]/' file
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/aGtb4A).

Comment: Thanks it worked :-)  Is there any possibility to get one blank line as mentioned in ques

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you try to remove the `[n] <date>` part of the files, which can be expressed using following regular expression:

```
grep -o "\[[0-9]\] [0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9] " *
```

As you see, using `grep -o` you can show only that part of the line.
Using `grep -v` you can exclude the line, containing that expression.

I was hoping that `grep -ov` would combine both into showing the entire lines, removing the expression, but this seems not be the case.

Can somebody give the last push and edit my answer accordingly?

Comment: `grep -oP "^(\[[0-9]\] [0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9] \K)?.*"` would do the trick, but I feel dirty just having wrote it.